# Give access of dynamodb tables to users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I created a table in DynamoDB and it works as expected.

Next, I have created a new user in the IAM and attached the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy to this user.

However, when I log in as the newly created user I can see none of the tables I created as a root user.

So, how can the root user, create new users and given them access to DynamoDB tables?

Comment: Did you check the region? Did you get an error when view the DynamoDB console?

Comment: probably region of user is different than the region of the table